# Latex package missing but tlmgr says I have it

Tags: latex

I'm trying to render a latex document I got from school. the problem seems to be coming from the document using the package "diagrams".

I get the error: "diagrams.sty Latex error: File 'pstricks.sty' not found"

When I go to the terminal and run `sudo tlmgr install pstricks`, I get the response `tlmgr install: package already present: pstricks`. So I'm not sure what to do next.

I'm using the app TexPad on MacOS and just updated my tex install via MacTex. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: In some cases two tex distribution can interfere. Can you a) show the .log file and b) show wht output you get from `kpsewhich pstricks.sty`

Comment: Here's the output from `kpsewhich pstricks.sty`: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty`

from the log (I can only post a few hundred chars here):
`
! LaTeX Error: File `pstricks.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> `

Comment: Please show the complete .log file. If it is too long to be added to your question, you could use https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Here it is, thanks for pointing me to pastebin! 
https://pastebin.com/LQbSg9zx